# Версия для слабовидящих

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Что посоветуете использовать для версии слабовидящих на Nuxt 3? На Vue 2 использовал bvi, но на Nuxt он не работает. Если есть какой-то способ использовать bvi на Nuxt, то не отказался бы от помощи.

Вот как импортирую bvi в компонент:

[image: импортирую плагин]

Вот какую ошибку выдает:

[image: ошибка при импорте]

Comment: @DaemonHK - [`npm install bvi`](https://github.com/veks/button-visually-impaired-javascript)

Comment: Что именно не работает? Вы ошибку показывайте

Comment: @DaemonHK https://bvi.isvek.ru/ - вот ссылка на сайт плагина

Comment: @VladimirGonchar дополнил скриншотами в теме

Comment: @alkhilaev_03 спасибо

Comment: @alkhilaev_03 а вы гуглить вообще пробовали ошибку? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931614/require-is-not-defined-node-js

Comment: @DaemonHK - ничего из этой статьи не помогло, либо я не знаю как правильно это использовать на Nuxt 3

Comment: Это не решение проблемы, хочу использовать bvi на vue, подскажите как подключить?